# Python Pandas concat function returns empty dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to do the following operation in python:

Source: [Set logic on the other axes](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#set-logic-on-the-other-axes)

[image]

Hence, I am using the following line of code:

```
result = pd.concat([df1, df4], axis=1, sort=False)
```

However, the result dataframe is empty.

Is there any reason why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: works fine on my side `pd.concat([df1, df4], axis=1)
`

Comment: Can you share a sample of your `df1` and `df4`?

Comment: yes, I will try.